# iPhone App rejected. 9.4 : Video streaming over cellular network (etc)

Tags: iphone, ios, http-live-streaming, bitrate

From Apple:

> 9.4
>
> We found that your app does not use the HTTP Live Streaming protocol,
>   with a baseline stream of 64 kbps, to broadcast streaming video, as
>   required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

This is not the first time we had this error. The first time we had this they mentioned the url that was giving the error and pointed us towards their mediastreamvalidator tool.

We fixed our .m3u8's, added a low bitrate stream, have run through all our url's with that tool, and they have all passed.

Upon resubmitting they gave us the error above, with no details. We've replied in the resolution center with the validation output attached and are currently waiting for a reply. Does anyone have any ideas of things we've missed that would not be caught by their validation tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after finally getting through to someone at apple on the phone we got a case number and our app flagged for a fast tracked review. It was approved and is now available, despite there being no change whatsoever in the binary between the last rejection and this approval.

Comment: How did you converted m3u8 videos in bitrate of 64kbps? can you give some details I am facing same problem not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must include 64kbps or lower bitrate stream (usually audio-only or audio with still images) in your streaming contents.

Check the guide: [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5)

> ### Requirements for Apps
>
> Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store must
>   conform to these requirements.
>
> If your app delivers video over
>   cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or
>   5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP
>   Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are
>   required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth
>   (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still
>   image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the
>   App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be
>   rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.